# Angular route animation

Tags: angular, angular-animations

```jsx
export const slideInOutAnimation =
  trigger('slideInOutAnimation', [
    state('*', style({
      position: 'fixed',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      bottom: 0,
    })),

    transition(':enter', [
      style({
        right: '-400%',
      }),
      animate('.5s ease-in-out', style({
        position: 'relative !important' ,
        right: 0,
      })),
    ]),

    transition(':leave', [
      animate('.5s ease-in-out',
        style({
          right: '-400%',
          position: 'relative'
        }))
    ]),
  ]);
```

hello, this code working but the scrollbar is not visible because of the `position:fixed`. How can I make the position relative after the animation is finished?

I tried many animations but couldn't do it alone.

Comment: export const slideInOutAnimation =

  trigger('slideInOutAnimation', [


    state('void', style({

      position: 'fixed',
      right: '-400%',

    })),



    transition(':enter', [

      animate('.5s ease-in-out', style({

        right: 0,
        position: 'relative !important'

      })),

 
    ])
  ]);

with this code

Comment: can you make a stack blitz example of your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using "done" event in your div and use a template reference variable (in the e.g. the "#div")

```
<div #div class="custom" @slideInOutAnimation *ngIf="toogle"
         (@slideInOutAnimation.done)="div.style.position='fixed'" >
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</div>
```

But your animation like (see how remove position -position is not "animated"- and how use width:100%, not left:0)

```
export const slideInOutAnimation =
  trigger('slideInOutAnimation', [
    state('*', style({
      top: 0,
      right: 0,
      width:'100%',
      bottom: 0,
    })),

    transition(':enter', [
      style({
        right: '-100%',
      }),
      animate('.5s ease-in-out', style({
        right: 0,
      })),
    ]),

    transition(':leave', [
      animate('.5s ease-in-out',
        style({
          right: '-100%',
        }))
    ]),
  ]);
```

See also you defined your "custom.css" like

```
.custom{
  position:absolute;
  background-color: pink;
  border:5px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box; //<---this to force border included in size
}
```

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jatk99?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)